# Testing Audio Input without actually using microphone

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

I'm trying to develop a site that uses Annyang.js (https://www.talater.com/annyang/) but I also just got my wisdom teeth taken out. So the problem is, I don't feel like saying words every time I want to test my site. (ouch)

Additionally, I anticipate trying to develop in public places or places like libraries. Is there anyway I can force an input in the microphone without speaking into the microphone?

I found this chrome flag "  --use-fake-device-for-media-stream " exists. But when I put it in the command line in chrome, it did not work. "Syntax error: unexpected error for ".

How can I test audio input by just inputting spoken commands instead of actually saying them and/or properly use the chrome flag?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that command should be working for you. Make sure you're typing in the correct command. I'm using OSX but here is my exact command:

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --use-fake-device-for-media-stream`

You may need to close all running instances of chrome.

You can also try typing `chrome://flags/` into your navbar to see what other options may be available.

Good luck!